# "Entry point was not found" error when attempting to expand the Results View

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ienumerable

In the picture below, `testScope` is an `IEnumerable`. I'm trying to see its contents by expanding the Results View, which according to Visual Studio will enumerate the IEnumerable, but instead, I'm apparently getting a single item with the message "Entry point was not found.".

However, the previous line of code (not visible in the picture) is `var thing = testScope.ToList();` and runs fine (it enumerates all the members), which means `GetEnumerator` is not throwing any exception.

[image: Screenshot]