# Visual Studio's enumeration during debugging (Results View): "Entry point was not found.":""

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, ienumerable, enumeration

In some cases, when trying to expand the *Results View* of an *IEnumerable* in visual studio might cause the error: *Entry point was not found.":"*.

So I decided to test a little, and I found out that it happens when the class has a generic parameter (which we will call *T*) and that implements *IEnumerable[Bar[T]]* (something that doesn't directly uses *T*) or something that doesn't uses *T* at all, like *IEnumerable[string]* (these may not be the only cases).

Here's an example class that visual studio cannot expand *Results View* properly:

```
class Foo<T> : IEnumerable<List<T>> {
    readonly List<List<T>> l;
    public Foo() {
        l = new List<List<T>>();
    }
    public void Add(List<T> l) {
        this.l.Add(l);
    }
    public IEnumerator<List<T>> GetEnumerator() {
        return l.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

And here's an example class which visual studio successfully enumerates:

```
class Foo<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
    readonly List<T> l;
    public Foo() {
        l = new List<T>();
    }
    public void Add(T value) {
        l.Add(value);
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        return l.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

[image]

This only happens in debug mode. If you try to iterate through the enumerable, you'll see it's working as intended.

Does any have an idea on why this happens or how to solve it?

This is probably a similar post to this one: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202302/entry-point-was-not-found-error-when-attempting-to-expand-the-results-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202302/entry-point-was-not-found-)

However, I felt like I wanted to provide some additional information.